# Time Machine back-up to older macOS version

Tags: backup, time-machine, high-sierra, mojave, compatibility

I set up a system today running High Sierra (10.13). I'd like to reformat it to run off a backup of my other Mac, which is currently running Mojave (10.14). For various reasons, I would rather not update the new system to Mojave at this point, namely software compatibility.

Is it at all possible to set up my new computer from a Time Machine disc last backed up with a newer version of macOS ?

Comment: It won't Restore 'downhill' but I've never tried it as a Migration rather than Restore. Give it a try.